# Python formatted string literal returns "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Tags: python

I'm using python cx_oracle , When I try to insert variables into sql:

```
cursor.executemany(f"INSERT INTO table ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders })",t)
```

it returns:

```
  File "eula_db.py", line 77
    cursor.executemany(f"INSERT INTO table ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders })",t)
                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Python 3.6

With t.py containing:

```
columns = 'abc'
placeholders = ':b'
s = f"INSERT INTO EULA_STG_DATA ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders })"
print(s)
```

the behavior depends on the Python version:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.16
$ python t.py 
  File "/Users/cjones/py/so15.py", line 3
    s = f"INSERT INTO EULA_STG_DATA ({columns}) VALUES ({placeholders })"
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

With a newer Python:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.9.1
$ python t.py 
INSERT INTO EULA_STG_DATA (abc) VALUES (:b)
```

Comment: The problem is I'm using python 3.5 ,but f only support python 3.6 up.

Comment: I'll update the answer so future readers can more easily find that info.